# Sharepoint foundation 2010 migration to foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-foundation, migration

I'm migrating from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 version. I've already created the new farm on 2013, but I have some problems on bringing the databases to 2013.

Can anybody give some tips?

I already have all the databases on the new server, but I'm having some different problems to sync the new site with these databases.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade the SharePoint 2013 is very much tested method. here are the steps you have to follow.

- Create & Configure new SharePoint 2013 farm
- Copy the database from old sql server to new Sql Server (sharePoint 2013 farm's sql)
- run the upgrade content database command.
- Last step, upgrade the site collection to SP 2013 mode.
- perform the testing.

Here is the [MSFT article for step by step](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/overview-of-the-upgrade-process-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013) or watch this video "[Upgrade overview videos for SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-overview-videos-for-sharepoint-2013)"

If you are facing any issue, please share the detail of the issue so that we can look into it.